# Keyboard shortcut for the Replace All button in the Find/Replace dialog in Notepad++?

Tags: replace, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Is there no keyboard shortcut (like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) for the Replace All button in the Find/Replace dialog in Notepad++?

Using Windows 7, 32 bit and Notepad++ v6.5.3

Comment: Are you sure Alt+A is not working for you in the Find and Replace dialog box? It is working for me.

Comment: Updated to the latest version and now Alt+A works in the Find and Replace dialog box. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can open Replace dialog box using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> as others have suggested. Once you set your `Find What:` and `Replace with:` text, you can use multiple options using `keyboard mnemonics` ([Mnemonics - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_(keyboard))). See the screenshot below.

- As you can see several controls with an underline character. These are all available using <kbd>ALT</kbd> key. So, to

  - **replace all - <kbd>ALT</kbd> +<kbd>A</kbd>**
  - replace one by one - <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd>
  - Wrap around - <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd>
- Give it a try. Look out for those tiny underline characters. Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + H is the only option.. (faster than ctrl + f)

Comment: I never said anything about ctrl + f. I am of course using ctrl + h to open up the Find/Replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

after ctrl+h pressed .. put some data in find and replace then click replace button using keyboard shortcut

Comment: Using which 'keyboard shortcut'?

Answer (score 0):

select the text in the editor --> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>; then <kbd>TAB</kbd> (write string to replace with); then  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> (to replace all occurences)

Answer (score 0):

### Now there is, because related bug is now fixed.

There was regression bug regarding this matter. [The fix was publicly announced in Notepad++ 7.2.2](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.2.2-released.html) on 2016-11-27. You can upgrade your Notepad++ to see this fixed.

I can definitely confirm I experienced this bug in 6.9.x releases (and maybe also in earlier ones). I also tested that in 7.2.2 <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> works again in Find/Replace dialog.

According to [older comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258950/keyboard-shortcut-for-the-replace-all-button-in-the-find-replace-dialog-in-notep/41648676#comment33134541_21258950), there was the same bug in 2014.